# Перенос БД MS SQL

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, windows-server

**Задача:** перенести *БД MSSQL* с одного сервера (*Windows Server 2003/SQL Server Enterprise Manager*) на другой сервер (*Windows Server 2012R2/SQL Server Management Studio 2012*).

Как это сделать с помощью графического интерфейса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все сводится к банальному Backup-Restore.
Выберите период без активности (ночь), сделайте бэкап на сервере с которого хотите уехать.

**Бэкап.**
Как сделать бэкап (очень кратко, информации по этому пункту навалом):
Пкм на имени базы в SSMS -> Tasks -> Back Up, в появившемся окне выбираем куда хотим сделать бэкап и как.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Разверните бэкап на целевом сереве.**
Тут тоже очень кратко.
ПКМ на имени каталогa Databases в SSMS -> Выбираем файл бэкапа для восстановления.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Готово.

Comment: Хорошо. Это я понял. Что касается прав доступа и т.д, нужно ли будет что-то добавлять?Пользователей, схемы и т.д

Comment: Да, все нужно переносить. https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server. Поскольку это не завязано на саму БД, это объекты сервера.

Comment: @sergosyr я рекомендую действовать так: Перенесите БД. Можно для начала без остановки. Потом перенесите все сопутствующее. Произведите все необходимые настройки и проверки. После чего просто накатите новый бэкап со свежими данными с вашего сервера. Все "система" переехала. Не забывайте так же про ПО (если оно есть и работает с БД). нужно менять строки подключений. Если у вас остались еще вопросы, рекомендую оформить их отдельным постом, а тут выбрать верный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать дамп БД, можно использовать к примеру Navicat для этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*(пкм - правая кнопка мыши)*

Comment: Хорошо, а без стороннего софта как можно перенос осуществить? Я поискал, наткнулся на метод Backup-Restore, но на работающей системе с ходу не хочется пробовать, вдруг что не так пойдет

Comment: @sergosyr Бэкап кагбэ не влияет на рабочую систему, кроме затрат ресурсов и возможного некоторого снижения производительности.

Comment: @sergosyr а в чём проблема скачать portable версию, подключиться к бд и сделать дамп? если нужен граф.интерфейс... Если не нужен, можно из консоли дамп сделать.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо, буду знать. С БД, к сожалению, до этого не работал

Comment: @Rikky Проблема в том, что в организации сторонний софт запрещено использовать(